# How to get all the inodes under the linux filesystem with python?

Tags: python, linux, filesystems, inode

I'm trying to do some calculations on inodes (Get their size, etc...)
All I found in the web was how to get the inode of a certain file or directory, but I want to get all the inodes with a single call, and then use them one by one have any ideas ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this?

```
import os
inodes = os.popen("sudo ls -Rli / | awk '{ print $1 }'").read().split('\n')
inodes = [int(i) for i in inodes if i.isnumeric()]
```

For my home folder, this returns a list of the inode numbers:

```
[11666512, 10223622, 10234894, 10223641, 10223637, 10617011, 10254828, 10249545, 10223642, 10223643, 10487015, 10223640, 11929556, 10223639, 10223644, 10486989]
```

To clarify, the `ls` command takes three flag arguments, `R`, `l` and `i`. `R` performs a recursive search to check all files in the folders and all subfolders starting with `/`, `l` formats the output to give us a list, and `i` gives us the inodes. We pass the results to awk to get the first column which contains the inodes and then do some simple cleaning of that data.

Comment: thank you for your answer, but its steel about a certain directory, I dont want to get them by directories or files, I want to get whole table.
I already tried to walk all the directory and files and get inodes for them, actually I need the filesystem table

Comment: @Godfather I updated the answer, does that get you what you need?

Comment: I tried this one too, but still I just get directory and files only in "root".

Comment: @Godfather sorry, my bad. I copied over the wrong line from my code. You just need to add the `R` flag so that `ls` will search the root file system recursively. I just updated my answer. hope that works for you

Answer (score 0):

You can enumerate all the inodes using the scandir function in Python3.

```
import os
inodes = [ ]
for dirname,subdirs,filenames in os.walk('/') :
    inodes.extend ( [ k.inode() for k in os.scandir(dirname) ] )
```

os.walk returns all the directories.
os.scandir returns all the entries in each directory.
If you want to get the inode of the starting directory you'll have to do that using os.stat.